# How to increase padding in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In draw.io, how do I increase the padding so that the content is farther from the sides of its container?

My situation: I've inserted a rectangle, double-clicked on it, and put in lots of text. I now want some more padding between the text and border of the rectangle.

Comment: And... how to increase padding for text labels on connector lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a rectange and set Spacing under Text tab.

Regards,